# How can I find what is giving access to a class?

Tags: c#, class, using

I am using VS2013 C#

I have a class that I want to access inside of my editor,
it is available in another forms code

using MyProject.Property.Color;

but in the editor form where I need to use a method contained in it

I cannot access MyProject.Property.Color;

How can I find what is allowing the access to this for the form is is allowed in ?

Comment: Is `MyProject.Property.Color` public? Where is it defined/implemented? In a source code file of your project, or is it provided by some other assembly/DLL?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more - I really have some problems understanding what you are really asking for

Comment: It is public and in a source code of another project within my solution. When I type Using MyProject. I get several other items, but Property is not one of them.

Comment: Ill try to explain a bit more, in my file: ColorTypeEditorControl.cs, I can using MyProject.Property.Color; in my file TimedSequenceEditorForm.cs I cannot, I am somewhat new to C# and do not know how to tell why I can use it in one file and not another.

Comment: You should provide a piece of the code, and take a look at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx) for understanding access modifiers.

Comment: I found it, so sorry, there was no reference set to it, I was making things harder than the needed to be. Sorry, and thanks for you time.